# how do i rotate a div or a object with a svg inside 90 degrees?

Tags: html, rotation

I have a phonegap project and want to rotate a single div or the object inside 90 degrees. i already tried -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); to the div an the object but nothing happens. Is there any way to rotate the whole div?

Edit:
forgot the "display: block;", now it rotates but the height is the max width and the width is the max height...

Comment: with display: block; it works!

Comment: Don't forget to also add transform: rotate(90deg); (without webkit prefix)

Comment: why should i add transform... without webkit prefix? it also works without

Comment: Webkit only works in webkit browsers... But i just saw that you're using phonegap, so yeah it should work.